# run prestashop hook by name

Tags: prestashop

I want to insert a hook out put to my menu element.

Store is a module in prestashop which hook right side bar.

I want to load the store module output in my menu elem

blockcontact module hook function

```
public function hookDisplayRightColumn()
{
    global $smarty;

    $smarty->assign(array(
        'telnumber' => Configuration::get('blockcontact_telnumber'),
        'email' => Configuration::get('blockcontact_email')
    ));
    return $this->display(__FILE__, 'blockcontact.tpl');
}
```

i want fire this module by some how which return this method output in my menu element.

Comment: please check grammar I can't understand your question. You want to display contact information on right column? Do you have a custom module?

Comment: sorry for bad english. i want to show prestashop contact module to my horizotal menu

Answer (score 0):

You can don't add new hook and use {hook h="[nameHook]" mod="[namemodule]"} in template files.

Sample: `{hook h="displayTop" mod="blocksearch"}` - this code display a content generated by blokseacrh for displayTop hook in place, where you using it